# Nifi ExecuteScript with Groovy : org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I am having issues with Apache NiFi execute Script processor.

Following the executeScript cook book tutorial
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-2/ta-p/249018, I was able to write a groovy script that writes to the output stream.

I am writing a Json string to the the output stream.

However on execution on Nifi, I get an error as depicted on the following link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8kZM.png

Below is the code

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback

flowFile = session.get()

if(flowFile == null){
    return;
}

def incomingFlowFileName = flowFile.getAttribute('filename')

def pathToIngestionScript = pathtobashscript.value

def command = '''
docker ps | grep 'visallo/dev' | awk '{print $1}'
'''
def containerId = ['bash','-c',command].execute().in.text

if(containerId.replaceAll("\\s","").length() != 0){
    /* "docker exec -i " + container_id + " bash < " + path_to_bash_script */
    "docker exec -i ${containerId} bash < ${pathToIngestionScript}".execute()
}else {
    /*ingest data like a savage*/
}

def result = ["fileId":incomingFlowFileName.tokenize('*')[1],"status":"2"]

flowFile = session.write(flowFile,{outputStream ->
  outputStream.write(new JsonBuilder(result).toPrettyString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
} as StreamCallBack)
session.transfer(flowFile,REL_SUCCESS)
```

Doesn't `org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback` exist in the Script execution space?

I am running Nifi 1.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `as StreamCallBack` but it is StreamCallback (without the capital B)

Comment: Thanks, couldn't have seen that sooner ;D

Comment: It happens to the best! :D